# Getting a QTreeView on a QWizardPage to update properly

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a `QTreeView` widget on a `QWizardPage` (say, `qwpage2`) where the flags for one of the columns of information depends on the state of a `QRadioButton` on another `QWizardPage` (say, `qwpage1`).

The original properties of the treeview column are set in the `initializePage` method of `qwpage2`. If I `Next >` through the pages, everything works fine. However, if I `< Back` from `qwpage2`, change the radiobutton on `qwpage1`, and `Next >` to `qwpage2`, the flags are not updated.

I have something like the following (in PyQt5) on `qwpage1`:

```py
rbtn1 = QRadioButton()
rbtn2 = QRadioButton()

self.registerField ("remove_checkbox", rbtn1)
self.registerField ("add_checkbox", rbtn2)

self.checked_choice.addButton(rbtn1)
self.checked_choice.addButton(rbtn2)
```

and on `qwpage2`

```py
add_checkbox = self.field("add_checkbox")

p = QStandardItem()
if add_checkbox:
  p.setFlags(p.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
else:
  p.setFlags(Qt.NoItemFlags)
```

How can I change the flag state (essentially the presence of checkboxes) associated with my treeview column if the page has been initialized previously?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about whenever you go back to the page after going backward from the next one, as `initializePage()` is always called, no matter if the "previous" page was the previous or the next in the page index (which makes sense, as page order doesn't always have to follow the "plain index order", since it's returned from [`QWizard.nextId()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwizard.html#nextId), which by default calls [`QWizardPage.nextId()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwizardpage.html#nextId) of the current page and could even return an index that's less than the current).
That said, there's one case for which `initializePage()` is only called once, and that happens if you set the `QWizard.IndependentPages` option. If you really need to use that, I think that the only alternative is to set values by overriding the page's `showEvent(event)`, and **only** `if not event.spontaneous()` (otherwise it will always process everything even when the page is shown again after being minimized).

What really matters here is that the checkbox of an item delegate is usually shown **if** a `Qt.CheckStateRole` is set for its index, because setting `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable` only means that the user *can set the item state*, **not** that the checkbox is visible.
In fact, unless some specific OS/QtStyle comes in action, setting that flag won't have any effect at all, and even if that happens, disabling it once the check state is set to any of the three states (Unchecked, PartiallyChecked or Checked) won't make any difference: it will be shown anyway.

While this might seem a bit counterintuitive, its behavior is clear from the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qstyleditemdelegate.cpp.html#_ZNK19QStyledItemDelegate15initStyleOptionEP20QStyleOptionViewItemRK11QModelIndex), where the StyleOptionViewItem feature HasCheckIndicator is set to True when and only the `data(role=CheckStateRole)` is not "Null", as in `None` for Python.

*Slighlty unrelated note: be aware that if you're using more advanced models (such as QSql ones), an "unset" value (as in a "Null" QVariant, eg. the field has no data set) is **not** always Python's `None`, but a "QPyNullVariant".*

Considering the aforementioned notions, you should set the model and its items in the `__init__` of the QWizardPage, then use `initializePage` only to set its flags.

```
class Page2(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.dataChanged.connect(self.setCurrentState)

        self.addCheckItem = QtGui.QStandardItem('item')
        self.model.appendRow(self.addCheckItem)
        # remember the default flags
        self.defaultFlags = self.addCheckItem.flags()
        # set the current "add_checkbox" value to None, which means that it
        # has *no* state set at all, not even an Unchecked one
        self.currentState = None

    def setCurrentState(self, topLeft, bottomRight):
        # remember the new check state
        self.currentState = self.addCheckItem.checkState()

    def initializePage(self):
        if self.field('add_checkbox'):
            # apply the new flags to allow the user to set the check state
            self.addCheckItem.setFlags(
                self.defaultFlags | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            # set the state if it has been previously set
            if self.currentState is None:
                self.addCheckItem.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            else:
                self.addCheckItem.setCheckState(self.currentState)
        else:
            # prevent notifying setCurrentState() slot that we're changing the 
            # value, while still remembering the check state;
            # note that blogking model signals is not a good practice, as it
            # prevents the view to receive model changes, which usually results
            # in painting, size, scrolling and mouse interaction issues, but we
            # can ignore that in this case, since those changes are only taken
            # into account once the view is shown, assuming that the view will
            # update once it will be shown, and that will only happen *after*
            # initializePage returns
            self.model.blockSignals(True)
            self.addCheckItem.setData(None, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
            self.model.blockSignals(False)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to write such a complete and informative answer! I have only been using PyQt for about three weeks and greatly appreciate insights from a master of the Qt toolkit like you. With a better understanding of some of these issues, I will try to break my code apart as you suggested.